# how to work with Map of String and List<Object> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, odoo

I did several google searches, nothing helpful came up. Been banging my head against some errors when trying to do something that should be pretty simple. retrieve data from list of dictionnary while connecting to Odoo using OdooApi in order to display it in a listview or any suitable design :

1 - creating a `home_page.dart` that contains a text field where to add `id` as imput

```
.
.
child : TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent)
            ),
            filled: false,
            //fillColor: Color(0xFFBB162B),
            hintText: "Numéro d'OR",
            ),
            onChanged: (text){
              num_or = text;
            },
            
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {_navigateAndDisplayCheckScreen(num_or);},            
              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
              fillColor: AppColor.secondaryColor,
              child: const Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Vérifier",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 26.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
.
.


Future<void> _navigateAndDisplayCheckScreen(num_or) async {
  final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CheckScreen( num_or: num_or)),
    );
}
```

2 - creating `check_screen.dart` to :

```
    class CheckScreen extends StatefulWidget {

      // CheckScreen({key, num_or}) : super(key: key);

      String id;
      CheckScreen({this.id});

      @override
      _CheckScreenState createState() => _CheckScreenState();
    }

    class _CheckScreenState extends State<CheckScreen> {

      var dt;
      String id;
      _CheckScreenState({this.id});



Future<OdooResponse> _getDataFromServer(id) async {
    OdooResponse result;
    OdooResponse res = await client
      .authenticate(email, password, database)
      .then((auth) async {
    if (auth.isSuccess) {
      print('success');
      result =
        await client.searchRead('account.invoice', [
        ['id', '=', id]
      ], [
        'id',
        'name',
        'number',
        'service_source',
        'origin_invoice'
      ]);
        print(result.getResult()['records']);

        final resu = result.getResult()['records'];
        // the error is here
        result = resu;

        return result;
    } else {
      print("Login Gagal");
      return result;
    }
  });


}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold( 
 
     body: Center(
     child: FutureBuilder(
      future: _getDataFromServer(widget.num_or),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: Text('loading...'));
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          else
            return Center(child: new Text('${snapshot.data}'));
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
  );

  }
```

Output:

```
data = [{id:10, name: Imad, number: 1344,origin: OR00348}]
```

And, i get :

```
he method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

Comment: Try to call it over `Future builder` or `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _getDataFromServer(widget.num_or),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: Text('loading...'));
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          else
            OdooResponse result = snapshot.data;
            return Center(child: new Text('${result.records}'));
        }
      },
    )
```

And your code method need to return the value `result`

```
Future<OdooResponse>_getDataFromServer(id) async {
OdooResponse result;
  client.authenticate(email, password, database).then((auth) async {
    if (auth.isSuccess) {
      result = await client.searchRead('account.invoice', [
        ['id', '=', id]
      ], [
        'id',
        'name',
        'number',
        'origin'
      ]);
      var dt = result.getResult();
      print("i'm dt $dt");
      print("i'm id: $id");
      return result.getResult();
    } else {
      print("Login Gagal");
      return result;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm having `null` ,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm having `null` , And when i try to debug it by printing the resutl in initstate    Future values;
  `@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    values = getDataFromServer(widget.num_or);
    print('im values $values');
  }`   `i get  im values Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' `

Comment: please check out the updated answer

Comment: same error  `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'`

Comment: change your return type `Future<OdooResponse>` from `Future<dynamic>`

Comment: i've updated my code, and now i'm getting a new error : `Type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type OdooResponse`